# Sort filenames in array that have a number in the middle using ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have a use case where a set of files are named as:

```
`a1@1x.jpg, a2@1x.jpg, a3@1x.jpg....a10@1x.jpg, a11@1x,jpg,a12@1x.jpg.... a99@1x.jpg,a100@1x.jpg`
```

when i read this in an array i get the order as `(files=Dir.entries("./pics").grep(/^#{fileNamePattern}[0-9]/))`

```
["a1@1x.jpg", "a10@1x.jpg", "a11@1x.jpg".... "a2@1x.jpg", "a20@1x.jpg"...] and so on
```

I would like to sort this array in ascending order based on the number after '**a**'

```
["a1@1x.jpg", "a2@1x.jpg", "a3@1x.jpg"...."a10@1x.jpg", "a11@1x.jpg","a12@1x.jpg"...."99@1x.jpg","a100@1x.jpg"]
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, its a really good idea to show sample code as proof that you attempted the solve the problem on your own, and are not simply fishing for answers. Failing to do that will get your question downvoted and/or closed.

Answer (score 4):

```
files.sort_by{|f| f[/\d+/].to_i}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
files=Dir.entries("./pics").grep(/^#{fileNamePattern}[0-9]/)
files = files.sort_by do |f| 
  f =~ /^{#fileNamePattern}(\d*)/   # Match filename, extracting number
  $1.to_i                           # Convert extracted number-string to integer
end
```